# Bootstrapping $R^2$ from a set of experimental data

Tags: inference, bootstrap

My question is probably best asked through an example.

> Suppose we conduct some designed experiment measuring how three different fertilizers influence the stem lengths on sunflowers, and we repeat the experiment five times (i.e. treat five distinct sunflowers with fertilizer 1, then another five distinct sunflowers with fertilizer 2 and so on).

The best way to go about assessing the effect of fertilizer type is obviously through a general linear model, namely an ANOVA. Suppose we fit our model and obtain an $R^2$ value of $0.91$. Of course, this is quite a high value.

Lets pretend that obtaining those 5 samples was incredibly difficult - so we wanted to make the lives of future experimenters easier by coming up with a confidence interval for the true $R^2$ value.

Would it be appropriate to use bootstrapping techniques on the experimental data to generate a sampling distribution for the $R^2$ value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is essentially what the bootstrap is for: approximating the sampling distribution for a parameter when that is unknown or difficult to derive. Like all methods, it will have difficulties in small samples. There are also situations where the bootstrap principle does not work. But that is for rare cases like estimating extreme values (maxima or minima) or sample mean for distributions whose second moments. This is not likely to be a problem with $R^2$. For more about this including situations where the bootstrap fails see my book Bootstrap Methods: A Practitioner's Guide published by Wiley or Efron and Tibshirani (1993) An Introduction to the Bootstrap, Chapman and Hall.